# Ideas to take a stream amongst 200-1000 servers and create one single file quickly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

We are in Google Cloud Platform so technologies there would be a good win.  We have a huge file that comes in and dataflow scales on the input to break up the file quite nicely.  After that however, it streams through many system, microservice1 over to dataconnectors grabbing related data over to ML and finally over to a final microservice.

Since the final stage could be around 200-1000 servers depending on load, how can we take all the requests coming in (yes, we have a file id attached to every request including a customerRequestId in case a file is dropped multiple times).  We only need to be writing every line with the same customerRequestId to the same file on output.

What is the best method to do this?  The resulting file is almost always a csv file.

Any ideas or good options I can explore?  I wonder if dataflow was good at ingestion and reading a massively large file in parallel, is it good at taking in various inputs on a cluster of nodes(not a single node which would bottleneck us).

EDIT: I seem to recall hdfs has files partitioned across nodes and I think can be written by many nodes at the same time somehow (a
node per partition).  Does anyone know if google cloud storage files are this way as well?  Is there a way to have 200 nodes writing to 200 partitions of the same file in google cloud storage in such a way that it is all 1 file?

EDIT 2:

I see that there is a streaming pub/sub to bigquery option that could be done as one stage in this list: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming

HOWEVER in this list, there is not a batch bigquery to csv(what our customer wants).  I do see a bigquery to parquet option though here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch

I would prefer to go directly to csv though.  Is there a way?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You case is complex and hard (and expensive) to reproduce. My first idea is to use BigQuery. Sink all the data in the same table with Dataflow.

Then, create a temporary table with only the data to export to CSV like that

```
CREATE TABLE `myproject.mydataset.mytemptable`
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
) AS
SELECT ....
```

And then to [export the temporary table to CSV](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data). If the table is less than 1Gb, only one CSV will be generated.

If you need to orchestrate these steps, you can use [Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows)

Comment: Thanks much @guillaume blaquiere   .  This helps a ton.  We will investigate.  "If table is less than 1Gb, only 1 CSV" -> Is this a BigQuery limitation? I am not sure but I was hoping Cloud Storage was perhaps like Hadoop HDFS where I could write to many partitions of the same file while in the GUI it looks like just one file?

Comment: GCS is like HDFS, but with more under the hood feature. It maybe (and surely) the case internally, but there isn't API to have the control on this low level access. About BigQuery, it's not a limitation, I think it's for performances that a sharding is done